# Understanding hashmap (with Arraylist as value) put method

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I'm having trouble getting my head around something I encountered earlier.
I have this class named `DictionaryOfTranslations`, which has a method called `add`.

The only instance variable this class has is a `private HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> dictionary;`.

This is what the add method looks like:

```
public void add(String word, String translation) {
    this.dictionary.putIfAbsent(word, new ArrayList<>());
    
    ArrayList<String> completed = this.dictionary.get(word);
    completed.add(translation);
    this.dictionary.put(word, completed);
}
```

The trouble I'm having is to understand why this last line of code: `this.dictionary.put(word, completed);` is apparently redundant.
If I comment this line out, the outcome is exactly the same.
My question here is: Why don't you have to specifically have to call the `put()` method on this hashmap, to add the updated Arraylist to it?

Comment: Yes, it is redundant, because of the `putIfAbsent` previously.

Comment: `completed` is a reference to the ArrayList that's in the dictionary and you're modifying it directly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Objects are not passed by value, their references are.*

When you use `put()`, the *reference* is stored in the HashMap. Similarly, if you use `get`, you do not get a *copy* of the list, you get a reference to the *same* list object.

If you mutate the Map through the reference, you mutate still the same object that is also stored in the map.

Thus, putting it back is simply not needed - you have already changed that very object.

Comment: "Objects are passed by reference in Java." No: ["Java is always pass-by-value."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value)

Comment: I don't think your first line is any clearer after the edit. I'd just drop it entirely.

Comment: @AndyTurner I like my answers follow the well established writing style of intro/thesis, exposê and conclusion. I think its fine just as it is.

Answer (score 6):

It is redundant because of the `putIfAbsent` previously. You've already ensured that it's present, in order to `get` it, so `put`ting it back again doesn't change anything.

Of course, this code is more verbose than it needs to be, and may unnecessarily allocate a new list. Instead:

```
this.dictionary.computeIfAbsent(word, k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(translation);
```

Answer (score 1):

It is redundant because the Object value you put into the HashMap is shared.

This on the other hand means you **cannot** do:

```
// ERROR
translation = new ArrayList<>();
Collection.addAll(translation, "he", "him");
dictionary.put("li", translation);
translation.clear(); // Should have been: translation = new ArrayList<>();
Collection.addAll(translation, "she", "her");
dictionary.put("ŝi", translation);
```

One has to add a new List every time.